# QListWidgetItem's text can't be highlighted / selected

Tags: qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I'm using qt5.2.1 on RHEL6

Aside from using `QTextBrowser` or rewriting a new widget that uses `QLabel` instead of `QListWidgetItem` like `QListWidget`, how would I be able to make the text individually selectable with the mouse pointer?

For example in a text editor like vim you can drag-click the mouse button over some text and release the mouse, and then you can middle mouse click in a different editor or terminal and it pastes it. I know how to do that through `QClipboard` but the problem is that the text isn't selectable in the first place. I still want the entire row to be selectable on a single click, which is why I'm using a `QListWidget`, but if I hold and drag the mouse I'd like to be able to select individual text.

**TL;DR**:
A `QLabel` has the function `setTextInteractionFlags` where you can make it mouse `selectable`, how can I do that for a `QListWidgetItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `QListWidget` can be used `setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectedClicked)` 
and for all items `setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)`, then on first click the item is selected,

[image: item selected]

on second the hole text

[image: all text selected]

and a part of text can be selected by mouse

[image: part of text selected]

Edit 24.03.2015

To prevent editing by user on this way subclass `QstyledItemDelegate` (i did it in PyQt5)

```
class MyDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self) 

    def setModelData(self,editor,model,index):
        pass # no changes are written to model
```

and use this delegate for listwidget:

```
self.delegate = MyDelegate()
self.listWidget.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)
```

users can delete or change the items text, when editing is finished, the original text appears

Edit 25.03.15: add

```
def eventFilter(self,editor,event):
    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress and event.key() not in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Control, QtCore.Qt.Key_C):
        return True
    return QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.eventFilter(self, editor, event)
```

to the delegate and users can't edit the text of the  items, they only can copy from him

Comment: This works but the item can be modified by the user this way. They can select text and then delete the selected text. I only want it to be editable through a dialog box that I'm using when the user double clicks the item.